Problem PyTorch/XLA TPU Profiling in Google Colab
I am engaged in machine learning in Google Collab. I use the environment with TPU. Previously, I used the following code for configuration:
!pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 torch==2.0.0 torchvision==0.15.1 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/colab/torch_xla-2.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
This code worked fine. But recently it stopped working. When I launch a cell with this code, a 403 error message appears. How can I fix this?
Internet search did not bring any results
